# When is the image of a convex set under a holomorphic function convex?

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a holomorphic function on a domain $G$ containing a compact, convex set $K$. Clearly, if $K$ is a line segment, then $f(K)$ might be an arc on a circle and therefore not convex. But what if the interior of $K$ is non-empty? Is it then true that $f(K)$ is convex?

Answer (score 4):

No. The map $z \mapsto z^2$ sends rectangles to nonconvex curvilinear quadrilaterals with parabolic arcs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I made the mistake to ask too early. The Riemannian mapping theorem provides infinitely many examples as well. I will check and vote for your answer as soon as I can. EDIT: But wait... Why is a sector of an annulus not convex?

Comment: See https://www.pacifict.com/Examples/Example48.html